# NodeJS: recursive tree browsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, tree

I'm trying to browse database results from their parentID, those results can be compared to a tree with multiple branch at each node, in which i want to browse it branch per branch (not level by level). Here is my recursive function:

```
  (function tail(file, parentID, entryCount) {
    console.log("TAIL CALLED: ", self);
    var opts = new Map();
    var data = "";

    opts["parentID"] = parentID;
    opts["Key"] = "";
    opts["Value"] = "";
    opts["RowID"] = "";

    self.Read(opts, function (err, rslt ) {

        for (var i = 0; i < rslt.length; ++i) {

          (function () {

            data = (rslt[i].Key + (rslt[i].Value != "-" ? rslt[i].Value : ""));
            data += "\n";

            var rowid = rslt[i].rowid;

            fs.appendFile(file, data, function (err, rslt) {
               (tail(file, rowid, entryCount));
            });

          })();

        }
     })
  })(file, parentID, entryCount);
```

This function give me level by level result, i think that i can understand why (the recursive call of tail is put on the stack and not executed immediately ?), but cant see how to make it work...

I tried with fs.appendFileSync() too calling tail under, but the same problem stay.

Answer (score 0):

use `appendFileSync` instead of `appendFile` to assure they are all written in order.

```
fs.appendFileSync(file, data);
tail(file, rowid, entryCount);
```

Your code will show each node on a new line which will be confusing (you won't know where a branch start and end). If you want to show branches starting from the root and ending on the leafs on one line you'll have to change the code (you'll have to accumulate the result in a string and pass it to the `tail` call and print it only if you encounter a node with no children then you'll print a new line character `'\n'`).

Comment: The for loop is still made before the recursive call to tail so i still have width result and not deph result :s

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 solutions to get depth browsing in NodeJS: one pure functional using serial callback and the second using async.series for each branch to force serial.